# django models. ForeignKey(User, default=request.user)

Tags: python, django

How to get default user?
For example

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=request.user)
```

Of course this code will not work.
This question was asked before but i could not find answer that satisfy me
Are there are any solutions for that situations?

---

Comment: You can't do this in the model. You need to set the user in the view. Remember there might not always be a request when you create a new object (e.g. you are running a script).

Comment: i can move this to view. Because i am not using my custom forms. All actions are going through django admin. Please explain me

Comment: oh thank you, i really did not see that answer.

Comment: but Alasdair this does not work for update

Comment: when another user updating object user does not update

Comment: What does not work for update? All you have in your question is a single line of code that isn't possible.

Comment: I used your function as you showed in answer `save_model`,  for example user A created an object and user B updated that object

Comment: when i want to get user it shows me A user, but i need B.

Comment: It did not updated user

Comment: Read the example code carefully. It specifically sets the user for new objects only. If you want to set the user every time, then you need to make a small adjustment to the code.

Comment: Please show me how to do small adjustment. I just don't know how to do this

Comment: Please explain me :(

Comment: That `save_model` method is only 5 lines including a comment. Go through it line by line so that you understand what each line does.